# Moq Setup not supplying AsQueryable method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following:

```
        Mock<ISiteRepository> mockSiteRepository = new Mock<ISiteRepository>();

        mockSiteRepository.Setup(m => m.Sites).Returns(new Site[] {
            new Site {
                SiteID = 0,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                Name = "A",
            }
        }/*There is no AsQueryable ?*/);
```

Here is my interface wth the implemented thingy:

```
public interface ISiteRepository
{
    IQueryable<Site> Sites { get; }
    ...
```

Any ideas?

If I do not put anything at the end of my Site array, it throws compile error:

```
Error   6   The best overloaded method match for 'Moq.Language.IReturns<James.Domain.Abstract.ISiteRepository,System.Linq.IQueryable<James.Domain.Entities.Site>>.Returns(System.Linq.IQueryable<James.Domain.Entities.Site>)' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: Do you have a `using` for `System.Linq;`?

Comment: Arghhhh, I didn't know I needed that! thanks brahhh! that's the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a `using` for `System.Linq;`.